# Any built-in way to do checkmark on the left and detail disclosure on the right, like in Wi-fi settings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a built-in way to accomplish the table cell below? (checkmark on the left and detail disclosure on the right)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use an image for the check mark. For unchecked rows, use a blank image with the same dimensions to avoid text moving horizontally.

Comment: Okay, so there is no built-in way to do the checkmark (like the accessory type). In that case, I will just use the imageView of the cell. You don't really need to use blank image, btw, just set hidden to YES.